# How can I sent a javascript object via href

Tags: javascript

I am building a javascript script that will go on a few websites ( clients ), get some info and return it to my home site. Since every website is a little different I need to do this in pure javascript. The way I want it to work is collect the info and store it in an object ( which I have working ) then send it to the home site with window.location.href. Without knowing what is available on each site ( for instance, they may not have JQuery ), what would be the best method of this?

The page it is sending to is a php script.

Example of object.

```
var obj = {
    page_on:window.location.pathname,
    loadtime:loadtime,
};
```

Then I want to send home in a function ( so i can reuse in different places )

```
function sendHome(obj) {
    window.location.href="http://domainname.com/handleinfo/obj
}
```

The code above is not working, its where I am right now. I need to do something with obj. I am not real good with javascript.

Thanks

Comment: Two major issues: 1. If you set `window.location.href` that will navigate the user to that page, away from whatever they are trying to view, so you should use Ajax. 2. You can't send an object, but you can serialise that object to JSON and submit JSON.

Comment: Can't use Ajax [across servers for security reasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) but might be able to use [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

Answer (score 0):

You need to serialise your object first. Then you can use [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) to send the data to your server.

Note that when your server is on a different domain than the websites you want to run your JavaScript from (it sounds like that), you need to enable [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) on the server, too.

Here is a sample of the script to send the data, given CORS is enabled on the server:

```
var obj = {
  url: window.location.href,
  loadTime: loadtime
};

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('POST', 'https://yourdomain.com/track');
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
req.send(JSON.stringify(obj));
```